# 400 Bad Request Spring Test Web Application

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-mvc, spring-test

This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/followers", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json" , produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Follower create(@RequestBody Follower follower, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Follower savedFollower = service.create(follower);
    response.setStatus(201); //Created
    return savedfollower;

}
```

And this is my test:

```
@Test
public void post_should_create_new_follower() throws Exception {
    Follower follower = new FollowerDummyBuilder().build();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String asJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(follower);

    assertEquals(0l, JPATestUtils.countEntity(em, Follower.class));
    this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/followers").
            accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
            contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(asJson)).andExpect((MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isCreated()));

    assertEquals(1l, JPATestUtils.countEntity(em, Follower.class));

}
```

But I'm always getting 400 Bad Request and I'm not able to figure out why...

Anyone have a hint?
**Update** Adding class Follower

```
@Entity
public class Follower extends AbstractEntity {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @NotNull
    private Credentials Credentials;

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private UserRetrievalStrategy userRetrievalStrategy;

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private SearchEngineFilter searchEngineFilter;


    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private IgnoreList ignoreList = new IgnoreList();

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @NotNull
    private FollowerStatus status;



    protected Follower() {

    }

    public Follower(Credentials credentials, UserRetrievalStrategy userRetrievalStrategy, SearchEngineFilter searchEngineFilter) {
        this.credentials = credentials;
        this.userRetrievalStrategy = userRetrievalStrategy;
        this.searchEngineFilter = searchEngineFilter;
        this.status = FollowerStatus.STOPED;
    }


    public Credentials getCredentials() {
        return credentials;
    }


    public void addUserToIgnoreList(User user) {
        this.ignoreList.add(user);
    }

    public IgnoreList getIgnoreList() {
        return ignoreList;
    }

    public UserRetrievalStrategy getUserRetrievalStrategy() {
        return userRetrievalStrategy;
    }

    public SearchEngineFilter getSearchEngineFilter() {
        return searchEngineFilter;
    }

    public void setSearchEngineFilter(SearchEngineFilter searchEngineFilter) {
        this.searchEngineFilter = searchEngineFilter;
    }

    public Iterator<User> getIgnoreListIterator() {
        return ignoreList.iterator();
    }

    public void clearIgnoreList() {
        this.ignoreList.clearList();
        this.ignoreList = new IgnoreList();
    }

    public void setStaus(AutofollowerStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public AutofollowerStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `Follower` class?

Comment: Have you tried printing out `asJson` and posting it manually to your REST endpoint via a client utility just to make sure the mock framework abstraction isn't interfering? Also, does your endpoint do any special validation on `Follower` and manually throw a 400 if it fails?

Comment: Yes, I print it, and looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem:

```
public Iterator<User> getIgnoreListIterator() {
    return ignoreList.iterator();
}
```

I added this method and jackson tries to serialize a field named ignoreListIterator...

Annotating with @JsonIgnore solves the problem.

**Update**: Better in this case use other than the Java Bean property name convention and change the method name to:

```
public Iterator<User> ignoreListIterator() {
    return ignoreList.iterator();
}
```

Thanks